# Clicking bookmarks in Google Chrome will blink twice before the website opens

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome

I have a problem with my 2016 MBP. The problem is, when I click bookmarks in Google Chrome, the bookmark will quickly blink twice before opening the website.

I am running macOS Sierra 10.12.3 and Google Chrome version 56 (although it doesn't seem to matter).

What's the problem? Should I go to fix my MBP, or is this normal for MacOS?

Answer (score 2):

That's just a normal visual indication that your click was registered. Same thing happens for standard macOS menu entries when clicked, although they will only blink once.

Comment: when clicking the macOS entries, they will blink once, I find that too. So you think that two blinks is normal? and what about yours? Anyway, I feel it strange...

Comment: Yes, it's normal. Happens the same for me also. It's just a stylistic choice from Google Chrome team to implement it this way. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. But in my windows PC, I does not find any blink when clicking the bookmark in the chrome, is that particularly designed for macOS chrome?